# Proving that a ring has an identity and $R$ only has $1$

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$=ring with identity $1$. If $d^2=a$ for all $d \in R$,The only unit in $R$ is $1$...show this.

I was thinking
$$1\cdot d^2=d^2\cdot 1$$
which equals $1\cdot d=d\cdot 1$.

I found out a unit means that $uv=vu=1$.

Comment: Something's up here. If a ring has $1$, then by definition it also has $0$ and $-1$.

Comment: @innerproduct note you can have $1=-1$

Comment: You need to work with the definition of a unit.

Comment: To prove something like this, assume that $u$ is any unit (i.e. there exists $u^{-1}$ such that $uu^{-1} = u^{-1}u = 1$) and prove that $u=1$. You will need both that $u$ is a unit and the special property of your ring.

Comment: @Mark Bennet just by declaring it so? Don't we need $0$ for closure under addition?

Comment: @innerproduct We need $0$ but it’s not a unit (except in the zero ring), so no claim about it is made in the question. The equation $1=-1$ holds in some rings, in particular in all rings with the additional property that $a^2=a$ for all $a\in R$.

Comment: @innerproduct The definition of a ring gives you $0$ of course, but the proof here does not require it. With the idempotent property it is easy to see that $1=(1)^2=(-1)^2=-1$. Think about the ring (even field) with two elements. I said "you can have" not "every ring must have". The rings in this question are Boolean Rings and all have $1=-1$

Comment: @Eike Schulte ah, yes. I glossed over "the only unit" in the problem statement. Thanks.

Comment: @ Mark Bennet Gotcha. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a \in R$ is a unit. Then there exists $b \in R - \{0\}$ such that $ab = 1.$ By the definition of $R,$ we have $a^2 = a,$ and so $a(a-1) = 0.$ But then $a - 1 = ab(a-1) = ba(a-1) = 0,$ hence $a = 1.$

(Note that $R$ must be commutative, so the order of multiplication does not matter.)

Comment: where is the a-1 coming from?

Comment: @Amanda if $a^2 = a,$ then $0 = a^2 - a = a(a-1).$

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is invertible, then $1=aa^{-1}=a^2a^{-1}=a$.